# R, opencpu: Is it possible to leave R running even if I close the web browser?

Tags: r, opencpu

I have a server (ubuntu system) holding an opencpu website and I have a long `for loop` of some calculations, which takes a long time. I wonder if it is possible to keep R running in the background even if I close the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this with a task of about 7s. Even after closing the browser, result files where produced in `/tmp/ocpu-store`. So it seems to work in principle. However, you have to keep in mind that there are various `timeout` parameters in the configuration `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` that might need adjustment.

BTW, I am assuming that your actual results are written somewhere on disk as a side effect of the function call.